# ReadProcessMemory expected ')'

Tags: c++

I'm trying to figure out this problem for hours... in `sizeof(int)` I always get this error

> expected ')'

I tried many fixes, like `(LPCVOID) BRO` or `LPCVOID 0x0055F9B8` or `LPCVOID (0x0055F9B8)`, but nothing worked. I tried to insert a 4 instead of `sizeof(int)`, but same error. I'm so confused.

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <windows.h>
#include <string>

int main()
{
    SetConsoleTitleA("boi");

    int intRead = 0;
    int BRO = 0x0055F9B8;

    HANDLE WINAPI hProcess = OpenProcess(PROCESS_ALL_ACCESS, FALSE, 13124);
    if (hProcess == NULL) { // Failed to get a handle
        std::cout << "OpenProcess failed. GetLastError = " << std::dec << GetLastError() << std::endl;
        system("pause");
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    BOOL WINAPI ReadProcessMemory(
        HANDLE  hProcess,
        LPCVOID BRO,
        LPVOID &intRead,
        SIZE_T  sizeof(int),
        SIZE_T * NULL
    );
    return(0);
}
```

Comment: Pointer: You need to _call_ `ReadProcessMemory()` function with the arguments e.g. `ReadProcessMemory(hProcess, (LPCVOID) BRO, (LPVOID) &intRead, sizeof(int), NULL);`. Right now, it is a function declaration in your code. You need to look at that.

Answer (score 2):

Your problem is here:

```cpp
BOOL WINAPI ReadProcessMemory(
    HANDLE  hProcess,
    LPCVOID BRO,
    LPVOID &intRead,
    SIZE_T  sizeof(int),
    SIZE_T * NULL
    );
```

Looking at the docs for `ReadProcessMemory()` it looks like you have simply copied and pasted it into your code. Unsurprisingly this doesn't work (pro tip, *never* copy and paste code you don't understand).

The issue is that you have provided the declaration of `ReadProcessMemory()` within your code, not called it. Instead you need to call it like this:

```cpp
ReadProcessMemory(
    hProcess,
    BRO,
    &intRead,
    sizeof(int),
    nullptr // This is C++, we dont use NULL anymore
    );
```

(Please do not copy and paste that code, try and understand it)

This code *calls* `ReadProcessMemory()` by passing the arguments it is defined to take as parameters within the documentation

Comment: ReadProcessMemory(hProcess, (LPCVOID)BRO, &intRead, sizeof(int), nullptr); 

fixed the problem thanks!